Is there a way to repeat a distribution of values based on Pandas GroupBy's counts between 2 dataframes?
I have two Pandas dataframes of identical structure, but varying shape and values:
import pandas as pd

dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6'], 
                        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
                        'age': ['18-25', '25-40', '18-25', '18-25', '60+', '18-25'],
                        'region': ['America', 'Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Asia']})

dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': ['id11', 'id12', 'id13', 'id14', 'id15', 'id16', 'id17', 'id18', 'id19', 'id20', 'id21'], 
                        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
                        'age': ['18-25', '25-40', '18-25', '18-25', '60+', '18-25', '25-40', '60+', '18-25', '60+', '18-25'],
                        'region': ['America', 'Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Australia', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Asia']})

I have executed a GroupBy on dataframe_1 to count a number of customers in each group and got a distribution in a form of dataframe:
pd.DataFrame(dataframe_1.groupby(['gender', 'age', 'region'])['customer_id'].count()).reset_index

It's output:
    gender  age     region  customer_id
0   F       18-25   America 1
1   F       18-25   Asia    2
2   F       60+     Europe  1
3   M       18-25   America 1
4   M       25-40   Africa  1

Is there a way to impose this distribution on dataframe_2 to get distinct customer_ids with matching parameters?
So, in case of line 0 (['F', '18-25', 'America']), it would be the only option of datframe_2, id13.
In case of line 1 (['F', '18-25', 'Asia']), it would be any unique 2 ids out of [id_14, id_19, id_21], etc.
P.S. To add some context, I am trying to create a group A based on a distribution of values in a group B, to evaluate results of an AB-test. I understand how it sounds but it what I was tasked with.

Please make a reproducible pandas example including dataframe_2 and desired output. You should reduce the numbers in that case.

You don't need to use pd.DataFrame() here; Series.reset_index() will convert to frame. Or just don't convert to frame at all; there's no need (except maybe for readability, but you could use Series.to_frame() for that).

Here's a possible solution to your problem:
import pandas as pd

# -- Input Dataframes ----------------------------------------------------------
dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'customer_id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6'], 
        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
        'age': ['18-25', '25-40', '18-25', '18-25', '60+', '18-25'],
        'region': ['America', 'Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
    }
)

dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'customer_id': ['id11', 'id12', 'id13', 'id14', 'id15', 'id16', 'id17', 'id18', 'id19', 'id20', 'id21'], 
        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
        'age': ['18-25', '25-40', '18-25', '18-25', '60+', '18-25', '25-40', '60+', '18-25', '60+', '18-25'],
        'region': ['America', 'Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Australia', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
    }
)

# -- Customer counts by 'gender', 'age', and 'region' --------------------------
dataframe_3 = (
    dataframe_1
    .groupby(['gender', 'age', 'region'], as_index=False)['customer_id']
    .count()
    .rename(columns={"customer_id": "customer_count"})
)
# dataframe_3:
#
#   gender    age   region  customer_count
# 0      F  18-25  America               1
# 1      F  18-25     Asia               2
# 2      F    60+   Europe               1
# 3      M  18-25  America               1
# 4      M  25-40   Africa               1

# -- Selecting n customers from `dataframe_2` using 'customer_count' values ----
# Steps being applied:
# Step 1: We start by merging `dataframe_2` and `dataframe_3` using the columns
#         'gender', 'age', and 'region'. We specify `how='inner'` to join only
#         values with groups that exist in both dataframes.
# Step 2: When we apply the merge operation, the resulting dataframe will have
#         the same columns as `dataframe_2` with an added column 'customer_count'.
#         We then apply `.astype({'customer_count': 'int32'})` to make sure that the
#         values from 'customer_count' are all integers.
# Step 3: Next, we need to apply another `groupby` operation, using the same columns
#         as group keys that we used to create `dataframe_3`
# Step 4: Instead of selecting columns and applying a "normal" aggregate operation,
#         we use `.apply` to perform a custom operation on each group of rows that
#         share the same 'gender', 'age', 'region'. In our case, we'll select 
#         N rows, where N is determined by each groups' 'customer_count'.
# Step 5: Finally, we reset the indexes of the newly created dataframe.
final_dataframe = (
    dataframe_2
    # Step 1
    .merge(dataframe_3, on=['gender', 'age', 'region'], how='inner')
    # Step 2
    .astype({'customer_count': 'int32'})
    # Step 3
    .groupby(['gender', 'age', 'region'], as_index=False)
    # Step 4
    .apply(lambda grp: grp.head(grp["customer_count"].iloc[0]))
    # Step 5
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
# final_dataframe:
#
#   customer_id gender    age   region  customer_count
# 0        id13      F  18-25  America               1
# 1        id14      F  18-25     Asia               2
# 2        id19      F  18-25     Asia               2
# 3        id15      F    60+   Europe               1
# 4        id11      M  18-25  America               1
# 5        id12      M  25-40   Africa               1

# Final validation: the sum of values from column "customer_count" of `dataframe_3` equals
#                   the number of lines that exist in `final_dataframe`
print(dataframe_3["customer_count"].sum() == final_dataframe.shape[0])
# Prints: True

Output:



customer_id
gender
age
region
customer_count




id13
F
18-25
America
1


id14
F
18-25
Asia
2


id19
F
18-25
Asia
2


id15
F
60+
Europe
1


id11
M
18-25
America
1


id12
M
25-40
Africa
1




You can use df.sample() to sample on the groups that you need.
group = ["gender", "age", "region"]
dist_key = dataframe_1.groupby(group)["customer_id"].count().to_dict()

dataframe_2.groupby(group).apply(
    func=lambda x: (
        x.sample(n=dist_key[tuple(x[group].iloc[0])], replace=False)
        if tuple(x[group].iloc[0]) in dist_key
        else x
    ),
    include_groups=True,
).reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2], drop=True)


Try groupby.cumcount() and pd.merge()
cols = ['gender', 'age', 'region']

g1,g2 = df1.groupby(cols).cumcount(),df2.groupby(cols).cumcount()

pd.merge(df2,df1[cols],left_on = [*cols,g2],right_on = [*cols,g1] ).drop('key_3',axis=1)

Output:
  customer_id gender    age   region
0        id11      M  18-25  America
1        id12      M  25-40   Africa
2        id13      F  18-25  America
3        id14      F  18-25     Asia
4        id15      F    60+   Europe
5        id19      F  18-25     Asia

